# How to find density of states in harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

Density of state should be number of states per volume .Why weThe take derivative of "number of states " with respect to energy to get density of states ?

Comment: density of states can mean density of states in the energy space, in the reciprocal space, etc... Density of states does not necessarily means number of states per volume

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong definition of 'density' here. In general:

$$\text{Density} \sim \frac{\text{Quantity 1}}{\text{Quantity 2}}$$

Quantity $2$ does not necessarily have to be spatial volume ($dV = dx dy dz$). In your case, it's energy, because we want to find the states available per energy interval (not spatial volume interval).